# STM32 interrupt handler multiply defined

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, stm32

I want to use interrupt handlers

```
void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  //body
}
```

but when I build the project, I get the following error:

> Symbol `EXTI3_IRQHandler` multiply defined (by stm32f10x_it.o and
>   main.o)

I have included library stm32f10x_exti.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handler `void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void)` already defined in file `stm32f10x_it.c`.
You can replace code of your handler from `main.c` to this special file or comment blank handler in `stm32f10x_it.c`.